# Creating a hash from existing data set <Key, Value>

Tags: hash, sas

Is there any easy way to create a hash object in SAS from a hash-like data set (i.e. a data set where one column is treated like `Key` and another -- like `Value`)?

Thanks and sorry if it's an easy question, I'm novice in SAS :)

Comment: You can define the dataset to use to load a hash object when it is defined. Or are you really just asking for what options exist in SAS for converting a value into a decode?  You could use a FORMAT or you could use the KEY= option on the SET statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `dataset:` argument tag. I lifted an example [from the SAS doc](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lecompobjref/67221/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p00ilfw5pzcjvtn1nfya9863fozd.htm) and simplified it to be minimal:

```
data table;
    input key data $;
    datalines;
531 yellow
620 green
908 orange
143 purple
;

data _null_;
    length key 8 data $ 8;
    if (_n_ = 1) then do;
        declare hash myhash(dataset: "table");
        rc = myhash.definekey('key');
        rc = myhash.definedata('data');
        myhash.defineDone();
        call missing( key, data ); /* avoid note re uninitialized values */
    end;

    rc = myhash.find(key:908);
    put data=;
run;
```

Your log should show:

```
NOTE: There were 4 observations read from the data set WORK.TABLE.
DATA=orange
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds
```

If you have a SAS/OR license you could also use OPTMODEL:

```
proc optmodel;
    set KEY;
    str color{KEY};
    read data table into KEY=[key] color=data;
    put color[908]=;
quit;
```

Comment: Great! It's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much ^-^

Comment: @Leo - You should consider adding some sample code to make this a self-contained answer.

Comment: @RobertPenridge, thanks for the advice. I concur. I've updated the answer.